# Estou a continuar um "formulário" de um site, usando JS HTML PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, radiobutton

A minha duvida é: Ao clicar num radio button, os outros "buttons"/outras perguntas que estão no simulador devem desaparecer, caso aperte no sim, se apertar no não não há qualquer tipo de ação,o button que eu quero dar a ação tenho de chamar no php certo? como?

```
<div class="layout_da_pagina" id="layout_da_pagina-container"></div>
<h3>a) Tem o Latout do seu site (Estrutura e número de página?)</h3>
<input type="radio" name="layout_da_pagina" value="sim"/>Sim<br/>
<input id="radio" type="layout_da_pagina" name="pesquisa" value="nao" />Não
```

Comment: facilita nossa resposta, coloca o código com os radio button e o button

Comment: Estou num pouco leigo no assunto, mas sim, consiga me ajudar agradecia:  <div class="layout_da_pagina" id="layout_da_pagina-container"></div>
<h3>a) Tem o Latout do seu site (Estrutura e número de página?)</h3>

<input type="radio" name="layout_da_pagina" value="sim"/>Sim<br/>
<input id="radio" type="layout_da_pagina" name="pesquisa" value="nao" />Não

Comment: Elabore melhor sua pergunta (edite a pergunta ao invés de complementar nos comentários). http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel?rq=1

Comment: Desse mesma forma ao clicar no button se sucede a ação.

Comment: Tenho varias perguntas com radio buttons, ex: "pergunta"---radio button sim ou não, assim sucessivamente, gosto é q ao apertar no sim, escondesse todas as outras perguntas e radio buttons.. não sei se estão a entender oq quero dizer..

Answer (score 0):

Acho que estou a entender oq queres dizer. Algo como isso aqui

```js
$(function() {

$('.sim1').click(function() {
$('.passo1').show();
$('.passo2').hide();
$('.passo3').hide();
});

$('.sim2').click(function() {
$('.passo2').show();
$('.passo3').hide();
$('.passo1').hide();
});

$('.sim3').click(function() {
$('.passo3').show();
$('.passo2').hide();
$('.passo1').hide();
});

$('.nao').click(function() {
$('.passo1').show();
$('.passo2').show();
$('.passo3').show();
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="passo1">
<h3>a) Pergunta 1?)</h3>
<input type="radio" class="sim1" name="pesquisa1" value="sim"/>Sim<br/>
<input type="radio" class="nao" name="pesquisa1" value="nao" />Não
</div>

<div class="passo2">
<h3>b) Pergunta 2?)</h3>
<input type="radio" class="sim2" name="pesquisa2" value="sim"/>Sim<br/>
<input type="radio" class="nao" name="pesquisa2" value="nao" />Não
</div>

<div class="passo3">
<h3>c) Pergunta 3?)</h3>
<input type="radio" class="sim3" name="pesquisa3" value="sim"/>Sim<br/>
<input type="radio" class="nao" name="pesquisa3" value="nao" />Não
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submeter" value="Submit"><input type="reset" value="Redefinir" name="B2">

</form>
```